# Firebase not updating to Node 12

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cli

Following the instructions here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#upgrade-node10

I have already changed my `package.json` engine to 12:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "12"
},
```

and my Firebase CLI version is:

```
firebase -V
9.5.0
```

However even after deploying functions it says I am still on Node 10:

```
node -v
v10.16.0
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `node` found in your command line doesn't have anything to do with the config for your firebase CLI in package.json.  Changing package.json does not affect your node installation in any way.  If you are working with Cloud Functions, the only thing that happens when you change "engines" is the target version of node used by the cloud service (not your machine) after you deploy your functions.

If you want to update the node version on your machine, you will have to do that independently of the Firebase CLI.  You will need to follow whatever instructions are relevant for your machine to do that (apt? homebrew? nvm? we don't know) - Firebase will not be able to help.

Comment: Simply downloading the latest Node version @ https://nodejs.org on your local machine is the fix (nothing related to Firebase) - Thanks Doug